# C# Finding typeof(type) in List<type>

Tags: c#, collections, typeof

Simplification of Code.

```
ObservableCollection<UserControl> controls = new ObservableCollection<UserControl>();

void main(){
  controls.Add(new Navigation) //Navigation is of type UserControl
  ... //controls.Add(new UserControl) for each UserControl
}
private void ToggleNavigation(){
  for(int i = 0; i < controls.Count; i++){
    if(controls.GetType() == typeof(Navigation)){
      controls[i].Visible = controls[i].Visible ? false : true;
    }
  }
}
```

I was wondering if there was a simplification for finding a certain datetype in a List.
So, I would like to have something like this:

```
int index = controls.IndexOf(typeof(Navigation)); //<--I am looking for a Valid Statement

controls[index].Visible = controls[index].Visible ? false : true;
```

Comment: Ignoring for a moment that your collection is not `List<T>`, and that in any case, you're probably going about this the wrong way, yes...you can easily filter a collection by type. See marked duplicate. If there is only one instance of the object (as your post above implies), it would probably be better to just store that one object's reference in a field, rather than searching a collection every time.

Comment: My code implies one item? I didn't want to type out every control.Add and just put the dots with a comment. And I guess I just ment collection. Was trying to have a more generic title. First time posting on this website. Wasn't able to find the thing I was asking about.

Comment: Even with your `...`, what you seem to have elided was the addition of other **non**-`Navigation` elements. So, yes...your code implies one item that needs to be found.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like:

```
var control = controls.FirstOrDefault(s => s.GetType() == typeof(Navigation)) as Navigation;
if (control != null) 
{
    control.Visible = !control.Visible;
}
```

Comment: `OfType<Navigation>().FirstOrDefault()` is cleaner and no need for (manual) casting.

Comment: More so what I was looking for. Puts me on the right track thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify to this:

```
private void ToggleNavigation() 
{
   for(int i = 0; i < controls.Count; i++)
   {
     var control = controls[i];
     if (control is Navigation)
     {
        control.Visible = !control.Visible;
     }
   }
}
```

This would work if you had multiple controls of type X that you would like to toggle visibility.

Comment: control.Visible = !control.Visible; that is way simpler! Thanks